# How, in ASP.NET, to force SQL Server to put a dot for decimals instead of comma

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I develop a web application with ASP.NET and SQL Server. I send data for insert and update into the database. In development everything works great, but when I put the application online, I noticed that the point of the decimal numbers is replaced by a comma that generates an error.

Do you have any idea how to correct this error? Thank you

Comment: Sounds like the regional settings of your production server are different. However to confirm we need to see the exact data and code you are referring to.

Comment: Sounds like you're treating or storing number values as strings somewhere you shouldn't be.